# Saving "post" link in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

So I've filled out a form and it's returned a result. Now if this was a "get" request, I'd see all the parameters in the URL, and be able to send the link to someone else to reproduce the result. However, I believe this is sent as a post request, so sending the link just goes back to the original page.

Is there anyway to generate a link that reflects the parameters sent for a post request? I think even if it's redone as a get request it'll work fine, the form probably won't care where it's getting it's data from.

Comment: As the bellow answer, you can create a book mark that create a from element with it's inputs values and submit it automatically and you can make use of the bookmark content as a url you can send it to some one to add it as a book mark to use it with one click post request as well

Answer (score 1):

I think you would need to create a bookmarklet that creates a  tag, with input fields, and then submits the form.